# fgetc returns a strange character

Tags: c, char

I am reading input until EOF with `fgetc()`. I am running into a strange problem. Right before EOF, I am getting a char `\337`. I am not sure what that is.

Here is my code implementation:

```
char *get_file_paths() 
{
        char *return_str = NULL;
        int chars_read = 0;
        size_t buf_sz = 80;

        return_str = (char *) malloc(buf_sz * sizeof(char));

        while((*(return_str + chars_read) = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF) {
                chars_read++;
                if ((chars_read + 1) == buf_sz) {
                        buf_sz *= 2;
                        return_str = realloc(return_str, buf_sz);
                }
        }

        return return_str;

}
```

For instance, if I had a string :`assignment_2/grepout.txt`. I am getting the following when viewing `return_str` in gdb:

```
assignment_2/grepout.txt\n\337
```

I am really curious what that means. I looked online, but there is no mention of it. Could it be platform specific?

I am running the following version of gcc:

```
gcc version 4.8.1 20130909 [gcc-4_8-branch revision 202388] (SUSE Linux)
```

And I am running openSuse.

Comment: The char \377 IS EOF. Just add `*(return_str + chars_read) = 0` just before returning from the function: it will overwrite the EOF char with the mandadory end of string zero.

Comment: That is strange, how is EOF getting added?

Comment: This line : `*(return_str + chars_read) = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF`doesn't prevent EOF to be added since it is a value returned by fgetc.

Comment: if the file has 80+ chars, there should be a check in the loop `if (chars_read >= buffer_size) break ;`

Comment: No Khaled, he resize the buffer with realloc().

Comment: @JoëlHecht: More precisely, `'\377'` is the result of converting the value of `EOF` to type `char` (assuming `CHAR_BIT==8`). The value of `EOF` is (typically) `-1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mark the end of the string.

```
return_str[chars_read] = '\0';
return return_str;
```

Comment: And what happens when the program input is 80 chars exactly?

Comment: In the OP's code example the buffer size is doubled when the 79th character has been read. So there is no chance of writing into unallocated memory.

Comment: And what happens if you type ÿ in your keyboard?

Answer (score 5):

It is important to not type coerce the return of `fgetc()` to a `char`. `fgetc()` (and fgets()) return `int` and not `char` exactly for the reason that EOF is a value that is outside the range of characters. Your 0337 (0xFF or 255 decimal) is a valid character in most implementations (It's character ÿ in Codepage 1252, in ISO-8859-15 and in Unicode).
With your loop, if you enter that character on the keyboard, you will have the same behaviour as EOF.

You should therefore change your loop to:

```
char *get_file_paths(void) 
{  
    int chars_read = 0;
    size_t buf_sz = 0;
    int ch;
    char *return_str = NULL;

    while((ch = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF) {
        if(chars_read == buf_sz) {
            buf_sz += 80;
            void *no_leak = realloc(return_str, buf_sz+1);
            if(!no_leak) {
              perror("No memory\n");
              abort();
            }
            return_str = no_leak;
         }
         return_string[chars_read++] = ch;
    }
    if(return_string)
        return_string[chars_read++] = 0;
    return return_str;
}
```

I changed several other small "issues".

- `realloc()` with `NULL` as first parameter is the same as `malloc()` so by rearranging the (re-)allocation in the loop you avoid unnecessary code.
- `sizeof (char)` is by definition 1 and does not need to be stated.
- The EOF value (i.e. -1) does not enter in the loop and is not mixed up with character 0xFF.
- The function returns NULL if EOF is already reached. It's a functional choice that can be helpful (or not). It depends on the context.
- Use array syntax (`a[x]` instead of `*(a+x)`), it's much, much more readable.

EDIT: Added allocation check. Used a harsh method. What could we do else in that case?

Comment: you probably meant `if ( chars_read >= buf_sz - 1 )`, and you need an initial `malloc`

Comment: Yes, indeed. Changed the allocation to take care of it (and still doesn't need a malloc()).

Comment: We should check the return value of `realloc` for `null` before storing it to buffer pointer. if any error happens we end loosing the buffer address. we should store the return value in a temporary variable and check for `null`.